# Magento pagination is not displaying on Catalog page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

In my magento website it is not displying page numbers on the bottom....In this website I have around 6-7 categories and every category has around 50 products

Changes I have made to the Magento admin panels are:

under admin -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Frontend 
[image: Catalog]

And under admin -> General -> Design-> Pagination

[image: Pagination]

I'hv only made changes in these
Still page number on the product page not showing on here

[image: Landing Page]

Any Ideas why its happening?

**EDIT:**

This is my `frontend\mgstheme\luxury\template\catalog/category/view.phtml` page

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$_imgHtml = '';
if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
    $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img class="img-responsive" src="' . $_imgUrl . '" alt="' . $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) . '" title="' . $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) . '" /></p>';
    $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
}

$settingDescPosition = 1;
$setting = Mage::getModel('mpanel/setting')->load($_category->getId());
if($setting){
    if($setting->getRatio()!=''){
        $settingDescPosition = $setting->getDescPosition();
    }
}

?>
<div class="page-title category-title">
    <?php if ($this->IsRssCatalogEnable() && $this->IsTopCategory()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getRssLink() ?>" class="link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe to RSS Feed') ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php $helper = $this->helper('mpanel'); ?>
<div class="custom">
    <div class="container">
        <span><a href="127.0.0.1/demo"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> / <span><a href="#">Products</a></span> / <span><strong><?php echo $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName(); ?></strong></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
<?php if ($this->isContentMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

<?php elseif ($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <div id="product-list-container">
        <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div id="product-list-container">
        <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($helper->acceptToUsePanel()): ?>
    <?php // description position below product list ?>
    <?php if($settingDescPosition==2): ?>
        <div class="builder-container inline-builder">
            <?php if ($_description = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
                <div class="category-description std">
                    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $helper->getEditCategoryDescription($_category->getId()) ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div class="category-description std">
                    <span class="placeholder">Add description for this category</span>
                </div>
                <?php echo $helper->getEditCategoryDescription($_category->getId()) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <?php // description position below product list ?>
    <?php if($settingDescPosition==2): ?>
        <?php if ($_description = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
            <div class="category-description std">
                <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved

Added this code to the `view.phtml`

`<?php echo $this->getToolbarBlock()->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/bottom_toolbar.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Check in the catalog.xml whether you have called xml for pagination. The xml should be as below

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
 <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</block>
```

As per your screenshot, you are using custom theme so please recheck all phtml files are in there folder related with pagination.

If still you are facing the same issue, so please see the below link that will help you :
https://support.webcto.eu/index.php/Knowledgebase/Article/View/43/8/paginating-not-shown-in-magento

Comment: I'hv not found any code for pagination in my code... Can you check it once... I'hv Updated my code

Comment: FYI, Its not the correct file that you have mentioned in your post :
frontend\mgstheme\luxury\template\catalog/category/view.phtml

Please check the below location and files :- 
    Layout :
app/design/frontend/default/<YOUR THEME/layout/catalog.xml
    Template :
app/design/frontend/default/<YOUR THEME>/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml
    Block File :
app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php

Comment: Pagination adds in catalog page using the reference "catalog_category_default"

<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>

Comment: `app/design/frontend/default/` here My theme name not available. Sorry I am new to Magento